# Matrix Proof Inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, induction

Can someone help me prove this please?

Suppose that $A_1,A_2,....A_m$ are all invertible $n \times n$ matrices. Then, $(A_1\cdot A_2,....\cdot A_m)^{-1}=A_1^{-1}\cdot.....\cdot A_{m-1}^{-1}\cdot A_{m}^{-1}$.

Base case $m=1$ : this is a tautology and true by inspection

Assume for some $k \in \mathbb N$ $(A_1 \cdot A_2,.... \cdot A_k)^{-1}=A_1^{-1}\cdot.....\cdot A_{k-1}^{-1}\cdot A_{k}^{-1}$.

Inductive step - let $m=k+1$: $(A_1 \cdot A_2,....\cdot A_k \cdot A_{k+1})^{-1} = ((A_1 \cdot A_2,....\cdot A_k)\cdot A_{k+1})^{-1} = A_{k+1}^{-1} \cdot (A_1 \cdot A_2,.... \cdot A_k)^{-1}$  by identity $(A\cdot B)^{-1} = B^{-1}\cdot A^{-1}$. Then I think the steps are obvious what I would do - replace $A^{-1}$ with the assumption and then use the commutativity of matrix multiplication.

Hence true by induction.

I think my inductive step is incorrect. Can I have some help please ?

Comment: $AB\cdot B^{-1}A^{-1}=A(BB^{-1})A^{-1}=A\cdot I\cdot A^{-1}=AA^{-1}=I$.

Comment: This is not true. I think you should prove that $(A_1A_2\cdots A_m)^{-1}= A_m^{-1}A_{m-1}^{-1}\cdots A_1^{-1}$, and then you're doing it exactly right

Comment: @Luukdr Okay I understand. how would I do that though ? Is it an application if the identity I stated ?

Comment: You use the identity $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$. but that identity is the case $m=2$ of the result you are proving. Thus it is unclear whether the proof of this case should be part of this theorem, or is something previously demonstrated that you can just apply. Certainly you cannot use "commutivity of matrix multiplication" because matrix multiplication is *not commutative*, a fact of which you should have been aware by now. It is associative: $(AB)C = A(BC)$. but in general, it is not commutative: there are $A, B$ with $AB \ne BA$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair What does the inductive step look like for proving what Luukdr sent. This is what I am struggling with

Comment: Have you tried multiplying $A_1A_2\cdots A_m$ by $A_m^{-1}A_{m-1}^{-1}\cdots A_1^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

For the base case, i.e. $m=2$, note that since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are invertible, their product is invertible and hence $(A_1 A_2)^{-1}A_1A_2 = I$. Multiplying both sides from the right by $A_2^{-1}$ and $A_1^{-1}$ respectively shows that $(A_1A_2)^{-1} = A_2^{-1}A_1^{-1}$. Now assume that $(A_1A_2\cdots A_k)^{-1} = A_k^{-1}A_{k-1}^{-1}\cdots A_1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
\begin{align}
(A_1A_2\cdots A_kA_{k+1})^{-1} &= ((A_1 A_2\cdots A_k) A_{k+1})^{-1} \\
& = A_{k+1}^{-1} (A_1A_2 \cdots A_k)^{-1} \\
& = A_{k+1}^{-1} A_k^{-1} A_{k-1}^{-1} \cdots A_1^{-1}, 
\end{align}
where we used associativity of matrix multiplication in the first step, the $m=2$ case in the second step and the induction hypothesis in the final step.